# How can I get the *original* data behind an NSImage?

Tags: macos, nsimage

I have an instance of `NSImage` that's been handed to me by an API whose implementation I don't control.

I would like to obtain the *original* data (`NSData`) from which that `NSImage` was created, without the data being converted to another representation/format (or otherwise "molested"). If the image was created from a file, I want the exact, byte-for-byte contents of the file, including all metadata, etc. If the image was created from some arbitrary `NSData` instance I want an exact, byte-for-byte-equivalent copy of that `NSData`.

To be pedantic (since this is the troublesome case I've come across), if the `NSImage` was created from an animated GIF, I need to get back an `NSData` that actually contains the original animated GIF, unmolested.

EDIT: I realize that this may not be strictly possible for all `NSImage`s all the time; How about for the subset of images that *were* definitely created from files and/or data?

I have yet to figure out a way to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ken, and having a subset of conditions (I know it's a GIF read from a file) doesn't change anything. By the time you have an `NSImage`, a lot of things have already happened to the data. Cocoa doesn't like to hold a bunch of data in memory that it doesn't directly need. If you had an original `CGImage` (not one generated out of the `NSImage`), you might get really lucky and find the data you wanted in `CGDataProviderCopyData`, but even if it happened to work, there's no promises about it.

But thinking through how you might, if you happened to get incredibly lucky, try to make it work:

- Get the list of representations with `-imageRepresentations`.
- Find the one that matches the original (hopefully there's just the one)
- Get a `CGImage` from it with `-CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints`. You probably want a rect that matches the size of the image, and I'd probably pass a hint of no interpolation.
- Get the data provider with `CGImageGetDataProvider`
- Copy its data with `CGDataProviderCopyData`. (But I doubt this will be the actual original data including metadata, byte-for-byte.)

There are callbacks that will get you a direct byte-pointer into the internal data of a `CGDataProvider` (like `CGDataProviderGetBytePointerCallback`), but I don't know of any way to request the list of callbacks from an existing `CGDataProvider`. That's typically something Quartz accesses, and we just pass during creation.

I strongly suspect this is impossible.

Comment: If you're hoping to get lucky with image reps, you should check if one is an `NSBitmapImageRep` and, if it is, call `-CGImage` rather than `-CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

For one thing, not all images are backed by data. Some may be procedural. For example, an image created using `+imageWithSize:flipped:drawingHandler:` takes a block which draws the image.

But, in any case, even `CGImage` converts the data on import, and that's about as low-level as the Mac frameworks get.